# Cannot understand cardinality constraint in clingo

Tags: constraints, cardinality, answer-set-programming, clingo

I have the graph coloring problem defined in Clingo as so:

```
node(sa;wa;nt;q;nsw;v;t).
color(r;g;b).

edge(sa,(wa;nt;q;nsw;v)).
edge(wa,nt). edge(nt,q). edge(q,nsw). edge(nsw,v).
edge(X,Y) :- edge(Y,X).
```

and I have the solution characterized like this:

```
{assign(N,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(N).
:- edge(X,Y), assign(X,C1), assign(Y,C2), C1 == C2.
#show assign/2.
```

I cannot understand what the `= 1` in the generate portion of the code means. I know that it is "set cardinality", but I do not understand how, as the code must generate seven nodes in each answer. Additionally, the following generator (which generates all combos of nodes and colors choosing in a set of length 7) requires an `= 7`:

```
{assign(N,C) : color(C), node(N)} = 7.
```

Here is a picture of the graph coloring problem I am solving: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sucr.jpg

and clingo: https://potassco.org/clingo/run/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{assign(N,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(N).
```

This means "choose exactly one color for each node". Or, more precisely, for 
each node `n`, pick one color `c` such that `assign(n, c)` becomes true.

To understand this better, we need to dig into the semantics of ASP.
Here N occurs outside of the cardinality constraint, so it can be viewed
as a "global variable" in this rule. The rule is essentially a shorthand for:

```
 {assign(sa,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(sa).
 {assign(wa,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(wa).
 {assign(nt,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(nt).
 {assign(q,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(q).
 {assign(nsw,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(nsw).
 {assign(v,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(v).
 {assign(t,C) : color(C)} = 1 :- node(t).
```

Now, this set `{assign(sa,C) : color(C)}` is just a shorthand for
`{assign(sa,r), assign(sa,g), assign(sa,b)}`. 
Now, `{assign(sa,r), assign(sa,g), assign(sa,b)}=1` roughly speaking means pick one element from the set `{assign(sa,r), assign(sa,g), assign(sa,b)}`.

If you look at clingo manual, the general syntax is 
`{assign(sa,r), assign(sa,g), assign(sa,b)} rel EXPR`, where `rel` is an arithmetic relation and `EXPR` is some expression.